# Asp Net Mvc 4.5 - How to to send a Json object through a return partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, razor

I have this link calling a action called UserSettingsTabsStructure:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(User.Identity.Name,"UserSettingsTabsStructure","Account",   new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "Get", UpdateTargetId = "conteudoDinamico", OnComplete = "loadDialogSettings" })
```

Then, when OnComplete is done, I would like to send a json object to a js function called loadDialogSettings.

This is the action:

```
public ActionResult UserSettingsTabsStructure()
    {

        return PartialView();

    }
```

How can I do that?
Even if a create a json like this:

```
public ActionResult UserSettingsTabsStructure()
    {

        Json(new
        {
            FormName = "Name",
        }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        return PartialView();
    }
```

I am not sure how I am gonna return the object with the view().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to return the result of the `Json` extension method:

```
public ActionResult UserSettingsTabsStructure()
{
    return Json(new
    {
        FormName = "Name",
    }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: The controller calls UserSettingsTabsStructure view that is a structure that needs to be loaded and then I am creating a dialog with this content. As I am creating a generic function to create a dialog I need the DOM´s element name to be passed to this JS function called on onComplete.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003901/passing-variable-to-ajax-actionlink-onsuccess-oncomplete-onfailure-etc

Comment: You should also consider jQuery as an alternative to the Microsoft Ajax.* helpers.

Answer (score 0):

I found a alternative way to do. I calling a callback function with a parameter straight forward.

```
OnComplete = "loadDialogSettings('parameter')".
```

Thanks